# CreateEvent failed when used in a thread (Delphi XE+)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, events, kernel, driver

I create a *Kernel-Mode* driver and do something in that.
And I have an *User-Mode* app written in Delphi called `MyApp`, for communication with the driver and `MyApp`.

I have to use `Event sharing` method between `Driver` and `MyApp`.

I am using a thread for doing this work. In the constructor of my thread I create a User-Mode event using `CreateEvent`:

```
...
var xxx:THandle;
....
 xxx:=CreateEvent(nil, False, False, nil);
```

And pass it to my driver and validate that.

But when this event is being created the handle of that is not valid, and when I try to use that nothing happens even any error or exception:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  while Active do
  begin
    if WaitForSingleObject(xxx, INFINITE) <> WAIT_FAILED then
    begin
        Synchronize(DoSomething)
    end
    else
    begin
      RaiseLastOSError;
      Break;
    end;
    Sleep(1);
  end;
end;
```

The driver create an event and pass that by the handle of this User-Mode event handle (xxx) to `MyApp`.

---

But when I create this event in main thread:
For example:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
 xxx::THandle;
begin
  xxx:=CreateEvent(nil, False, False, nil);
end;
```

The handle of event (`xxx`) is a valid handle !!!

**Edit:**

When I use Delphi 7 the xxx handle is valid! Only in XE+ it is not valid.
Edit my code!

Notice that I have to use threading and I have to create event in `MyThread`.
Any idea?

(Excuse me if my English is bad)

Comment: `the handle is not valid` - How do you determine the validity of the handle?

Comment: I validate handle in kernel-mode !

Comment: @JensG When in kernel i use the `ObReferenceObjectByHandle` can determine the passed handle from use-land is valid or not.

Comment: I guess the problem is eventually the context where your driver and user app runs. I would suggest you switch to named events which can be shared between processes. Check out http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=108

Comment: @mrabat Thanks for link (I saw this link in the past). My problem isn't in Kernel-Mode section, My problem is in the User mode app, Because when i use Delphi 7 my code work correctly but when compile the same code by Delphi XE+ this problem occur!

Comment: Do we need the driver to reproduce this? It is very unclear to me. A handle in the user process is not valid in your kernel mode driver. You don't appear to be doing much error checking.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes you need driver.It is very unclear to me too. when i use Delphi 7 it work correctly but when use XE3 and when i pass User-mode event handle to driver and call the `ObReferenceObjectByHandle` in driver for getting user mode handle for kernel i got `0xc0000008` error(An invalid HANDLE) .

Comment: Well, it's your job to make the question clear to us. At the moment it is not,

Comment: It appears you have working code in Delphi 7 that causes errors when compiled in XE3.  Are there any other differences?  Are you testing on different operating systems?  (WinXP vs Win7?) Are you targeting different compilers?  (x86 vs x64?)

Comment: But you're creating the event in the main thread anyway, TThread constructor runs in the main thread.

Comment: @J... The code has not any differences , I test my code on Win7 x64 and Win7 SP1 x64 and test only on x86 (Delphi Compile)